# Build a colorbar from a grayscale image

Tags: java, c++, c, colors

I've an 8-bit grayscale image representing intensities. I would like to display it with color according the intensity value (to be clear,something like this http://www.matthiaspospiech.de/files/matlab/plot/pcolor/pcolor-example-simple.png).

I tried with an HSV scale (with H in (0->85) or (85->140) or (140->255) and then go back to RGB but it seems not to work. Does any have an idea ? Here is my code: (it runs in loops on `i` and `j`, `img` is the grayscale image,

```
grey = img[j*w+i];                                                                                             

H = (grey * 360.0) / 255 ;
X = 1-((int)abs((int)(h/60.0) % 2) - 1);

if(BETWEEN(H,0,60) || BETWEEN(H,300,360)) r = 1.0;
else if(BETWEEN(H,60,120) || BETWEEN(H,240,300)) r = X;
else r = 0;

if(BETWEEN(H,60,180)) g = 1.0;
else if(H >= 240) g = 0;
else g = X;

if(BETWEEN(H,180,300)) b = 1.0;
else if(H < 120) b = 0;
else b = X;

R = (int)(r*255.0);
G = (int)(g*255.0);
B = (int)(b*255.0);
```

(the final goal is to use it in a Java program with OpenImaj so if someone knows something about it, it's fine too :) )

Comment: why the C++ and C tags if you want to do it in Java?

Comment: because it's more easier for me now to test it in C/C++ (with SDL) :)

Comment: As given, that is neither java, nor c nor c++. Please pick a language tag, do not just specify all available.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: As given, it can be Java or C/C++ (because it's actually C/C++), I picked just the useful part of the code

Comment: It's not complicated : i have a 8-bit image, i want to display it in color with an intensity scale as showed in the given link.

Comment: Create a table of 256 entries to store the R G B for each grey scale intensity. Don't do the color calculations for every pixel, just look up the values from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the HSB system. Set S to 100 (full saturation). Set B to 100 (maximum brightness). I suppose your grey in in [0,255], set H to (1-(grey/255.0))*240.

This will roughly produces something like the given picture. When grey=0, H will be 240° so blue, and when grey=255, H will be 0° so red...

You can also modify B to obtain bright or deep colors...

HVB to RGB conversion can be found on the web if not available in your API.